# Cannot call 'security' with 'resolution'=series[string]. The argument should be of type: string;

Tags: pine-script

I am attempting to update a script (someone else's) to Pine Script v4.  The original script ([All Squeezes](https://www.tradingview.com/script/SxufSlwl-all-squeezes/)) uses multiple timeframes, and I'm having trouble updating the security() call.

Here is what I believe the relevant sections of code:

```
true_interval = tonumber(timeframe.period) * (timeframe.ismonthly ? 30 * 1440 : timeframe.isweekly ? 7 * 1440 : timeframe.isdaily ? 1440 : 1)
_15tf = true_interval >= 120 ? 60 : 15
_15c = security(syminfo.tickerid, tostring(_15tf), close, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

I'm afraid the series[string] vs type: string; error is very confusing to me, and I don't know how to proceed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As per compilation error, **security()** function doesn't accept series for resolution= argument.
tonumber() and tostring() function's output will always be a series.

1. Instead of `tonumber(timeframe.period)` use `timeframe.multiplier` as it returns an integer of the timeframe resolution.
2. Declare a simple string (instead of the integer that is later transformed to string) directly in the _15tf conditional - `... ? '60' : '15'`.

--

```
//@version=4
study("")
true_interval = timeframe.multiplier * (timeframe.ismonthly ? 30 * 1440 : timeframe.isweekly ? 7 * 1440 : timeframe.isdaily ? 1440 : 1)
_15tf = true_interval >= 120 ? '60' : '15'
_15c = security(syminfo.tickerid, _15tf, close, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(_15c)
```

PS!: lookahead without data offset == repaint.